# Convert Arc<RwLock> to &mut

Tags: rust

I am trying to have a value in a trait that can be mutated by means of a reference. The problem is that the `String` values are very large and may be accessed by many threads, so my solution looks something like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn name<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut String;
}

struct SimpleImpl {
    name: String
}

impl MyTrait for SimpleImpl {
    fn name<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut String {
        &mut self.name
    }
}

use std::sync::{Arc,RwLock};

struct ParallelImpl {
    name: Arc<RwLock<String>>
}

impl MyTrait for ParallelImpl {
    fn name<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut String {
        self.name.get_mut().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = SimpleImpl { name: String::from("simple") };
    let mut b = ParallelImpl { name: Arc::new(RwLock::new(String::from("parallel"))) };

    a.name().as_mut_str();
    b.name().as_mut_str();
}
```

This fails to compile with

```
main2.rs:23:9: 23:18 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
main2.rs:23         self.name.get_mut().unwrap()
```

Why can't I call `get_mut()` to unwrap both the `Arc` and the `RwLock`?

Comment: This looks like another job for the [`owning_ref`](https://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html) crate.  It includes a [`RwLockWriteGuardRef`](https://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/type.RwLockWriteGuardRef.html) type which behaves much like a reference but keeps hold of the guard.

Answer (score 7):

Have a better look at the interface of `RwLock`.

[`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html#method.get_mut) returns a `LockResult<&mut T>` which is a guard object. The destruction of this guard automatically unlocks the lock.

In order for things to be safe, the `&mut T` that you get by calling `unwrap()` on the guard is *borrowing from the guard*, that is, the lifetime of the result of `unwrap()` is limited by that of the guard (since after the guard is destroyed, the lock is unlocked).

And here, you are creating a temporary guard and throwing it away immediately, so the lifetime of the reference cannot exceed that of the function...

**Congratz to Rust!** Yet another data race prevented at compile-time :)

Comment: So I have to return a `LockResult<&mut T>` from `name()`?

Comment: @JohnMcCrae Another would be to design the API along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40853817/1600898). That would allow the same interface in parallel and non-parallel case.

Comment: @JohnMcCrae: Well, it's a bit more complicated. Until Rust implements the ability to parameterize an associated type with a lifetime, it's unfortunately impossible to return different types borrowing `Self` from different implementations of a trait...