# Lifetime issue with a lazy_static mutable variable

Tags: rust, lifetime

I use `lazy_static` to keep a `HashMap` in the memory. With two methods I am adding and getting elements, but I am having some problems with lifetimes.

This is my code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref HASHMAP: Mutex<HashMap<String, Foo>> = Mutex::new({
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("one".to_string(), Foo{param1:"foo1".to_string(),    param2:"foo2".to_string()} );
        m.insert("two".to_string(), Foo{param1:"bar1".to_string(), param2:"bar2".to_string()});
        m
    });
}

pub struct Foo{
    param1: String,
    param2: String,
}

pub fn ins_val(name: String, f: Foo){
    HASHMAP.lock().unwrap().insert(name, f);
}

pub fn get_val(k: &str) -> Option<&Foo>{
    HASHMAP.lock().unwrap().get(k)
}
```

And this is the error:

```
HASHMAP.lock().unwrap().get(k) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust is correctly preventing a bug here.

Your `get_val` function is trying to return a reference into `HASHMAP`, but this isn't safe unless you continue holding the lock, as someone else could otherwise come and modify the map under your feet.

You need to either keep the lock until you return the value (by returning the mutex guard along with the value; for example using [`MutexGuardRef`](http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/type.MutexGuardRef.html) from the `owning_ref` crate), or copy the value instead of returning a reference:

```
pub fn get_val(k: &str) -> Option<Foo> {
    HASHMAP.lock().unwrap().get(k).cloned()
}
```

With this implementation `Foo` would of course need to implement `Clone`.

Comment: Another option is to change the interface to accept a closure that gets a reference into the map, which can choose whether to return a copy of the reference, or just inspect it. More details [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40853817/1600898).

Comment: Note that you can use `option.cloned()` as a shorthand for `option.map(Clone::clone)`.